# Can I charge my new iPhone with iMac

Tags: iphone, charger

Recently I bought an iPhone online and it's delivered to me today. I don't have a charger brick with me and the charger I ordered is still on the way and will reach me only by tomorrow EOD, so is it okay it charge my iPhone for the first time by connecting to the iMac 2017 I have, as I don't have any other Apple devices.

Will it harm the battery health if I slowly charge it from the iMac USB out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can charge any Apple Device (or any device that supports charging over USB-C for that matter) using your iMac without danger of damage. USB-C PD (PowerDelivery) is standardised and the devices will negotiate the proper charging parameters.

Comment: If memory serves me right the 2017 iMacs output 10W over USB-C, so keep in mind that your phone will charge slower than if using a Power Brick with more max. output.

Comment: So hope it doesn't harm the device for a first charge ? There are a lot of myths regarding first full cycle charge thats why i am worried as its my first iphone :-)

Comment: No, charging it "slowly" will not hurt the battery. As a general rule of thumb higher charging speeds mean higher wear on the battery, but the differences are slight.

Comment: Lastly, one more question, i have ordered the 20W charger so does it affect the BH ?

Comment: It won't need a 'first charge' btw, it will be 80% charged when you get it, not like the old days when things would arrive flat & you had to wait for them to charge before you could use them. That doesn't work so well for new Li-ion batteries.

Comment: @Tetsujin I received it like a 60% charged device. This is my first iphone, thats why i am little panic

Comment: @FortuneCookie even 60% is fine, no need to worry